# Can an object have 0 acceleration because its instantaneous velocity is 0?

Tags: kinematics

If  an object has an instantaneous velocity of zero, does this mean that its acceleration is zero?

Answer (score 2):

Throw a ball in the air. At its apogee (highest point) its velocity is zero. However, it is still accelerated down at 9.8 $m/s^2$.